# jQuery Won't Work in Adobe Brackets

Tags: jquery, adobe-brackets

I know this has been asked before, but after looking for a while, I haven't been able to find any way to add jQuery to Brackets. I copied and pasted the code from my website into the editor and get many errors,even though my website works exactly like I would like it to. The live preview also doesn't work with jQuery, but everything else works.

Anything Helps!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to include your `<script></script>` tags at the bottom of your HTML code, before the closing `</body>` tag? That means the HTML of your page will be already loaded by the time the script is run.

The order you place each of your  `<script></script>` tags is also important. Remember to include the jQuery CDN/file before you include code that uses jQuery.

It might look similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head> .. </head>
  <body>
    <div class="your-content"> .. </div>
    <footer class="your-footer"> .. </footer>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/yourcode.js"></script> 
  </body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're developing locally you can still load jquery from the google cdn, but you may need to add the http back into the link:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Done that already. Done everything needed to add it do webpage. Still does't work